# Replicating Tutorial but received error with Pandas. Code out of date possible?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently replicating this tutorial [here](http://www.danielforsyth.me/analyzing-a-nhl-playoff-game-with-twitter/) trying to do some measurements on a convention that recently occurred. However, on trying to replicate the data visualization aspects of the tutorial I am getting an error that I cannot find a solution to.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import TimeGrouper
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
anthrocon = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Anthrocon\tweets.csv')
anthrocon['createdat'] = pd.todatetime(pd.Series(anthrocon['createdat']))
anthrocon.setindex('createdat', drop=False, inplace=True)
anthrocon.index = anthrocon.index.tzlocalize9('GMT').txconvert('EST')
anthrocon.index = anthrocon.index - DateOffSet(hours = 12)
anthrocon.index
```

There are two big errors I am getting right now. One is that Python returns that there is no module for the pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffSet. It returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\database.py", line 2, in <module>
from pandas.tseries.resample import DatetimeIndex, TimeGrouper
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.tseries.resample'
```

I've looked up the same error but I have not found anything too helpful, and I've reinstalled pandas several times to see if that rectifys the issue. Is my code out of date here?

Now if I attempt to remove the code for the sake of just moving forward with the project I return an error that seems to be related to the code above. Python is unable to locate todatetime

The error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File "D:\database.py", line 1
import pandas as pd
DtypeWarning: Columns (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,22,30,31) have mixed types. 
Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\database.py", line 4, in <module>
anthrocon['createdat'] = pd.todatetime(pd.Series(anthrocon['createdat']))
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'todatetime'code here
```

I would greatly appreciate any input or point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I figured out the tutorial did not have a proper to_datetime it forgot the underscore. Sorry about that!